# Getting values from checkbox, add them, and display the result

Tags: jquery, checkbox, addition

I'm having some checkboxes, where all have different values but all numbers.

I want to get the values that are checked, and then add the numbers together and then display the result in my div.

```
<div id="pakker">
<input type="checkbox" value="39" />test 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="79" />test 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="29" />test 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="49" />test 4<br/>
ect
</div>
```

What I have so far is this: `var pakker = $('#pakker checkbox:checked').val();`

**UPDATE:**
Where i want the result: `<h1 id="sk">0</h1>`

But it's not really working, although I'm not getting any errors.

Does anyone know how this can be done, as easily as possible?

Comment: You're using `checkbox` as a selector but there's no such tag name. I believe you're looking for `:checkbox` (that leading colon is important!), and then you're going to have to use something different than `.val` to handle the multiple objects returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can see what to do: http://jsfiddle.net/vaKWs/6/

Updated to sum values automatically.

Comment: Thank you, but there should be no button, it needs to be shown automaticly

Answer (score 5):

You can select checkboxes using an [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector (you could also use the `:checkbox` selector, but that's slower). You would then need to [iterate](http://api.jquery.com/each/) over the set of checked checkboxes and keep a running total of the values:

```
var total = 0;
$("#pakker input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
});
//Do whatever you like with total
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nrg4R/5/).

Comment: Thanks, did the job with adding ect.. but when i press "test 2" i cant see the result ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. If you want something to happen when you click on the checkbox, you'll have to bind a `click` or `change` event listener to the checkboxes.

Comment: Okay, so something like this ? $(function() {
   $('#pakker :checked').click(updateSK);
   updateSK(); -another new function
 });

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = 0;
$("#pakker input:checked").each(function(){ result += $(this).val(); });

alert(result );
```

Comment: parse integer `$("#pakker input:checked").each(function(){ result = parseInt($(this).val())+parseInt(result); }); `

Answer (score 0):

If you are fortunate enough to not support older browsers (or [shim `reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility))...

```
var sum = $('#pakker :checkbox:checked').map(function() {
   return parseInt(this.value, 10);
}).get().reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return prev + current;
}, 0);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/QX4Tm/).

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
            var total = 0;
            $("#pakker input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
                total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
            });
            $('#result').html(total);
        });
    });
```

Result:

```
<span id="result"></span>
<div id="pakker">
<input type="checkbox" value="39" />test 1 - value 39<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="79" />test 2 - value 79<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="29" />test 3 - value 29<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="49" />test 4 - value 49<br/>
ect
</div>
```